# Форматирование жесткого диска

Tags: unix

Если я форматирую жесткий диск, затрется ли код моей ОС?

Comment: Многие OS не дадут форматнуть диск, на котором они находятся. Если unіх разрешит такое форматирование и ОІ находится на этом диске - то да (сотрется код который на диске).

Comment: Если там, где вы форматируете, лежит ОС, то затрётся. Если не лежит, то не затрётся. \*замер в ожидании лодки\*

Comment: Форматирование уничтожает все данные на форматируемом разделе/накопителе. Так что если файлы ОС находятся на том же разделе, то да, затрётся. Но то что уже было загружено в оперативную память, останется в целости.

Comment: очень интересно. А если я форматнул хард, то код ОС который был в оперативке сохранится на хард назад?(звучит как то бредово))

Comment: Теоретически сделать так ничего не мешает :) Но большинство современных ОС с такими извращениями не заморачиваются, насколько я знаю, и просто продолжат жить на остатках, находящихся в оперативке, до перезагрузки

Comment: А не вся ОС всегда в памяти. Ядро да, но ведь есть еще система запуска, которая только при включении загружается, отрабатывает и удаляется из памяти. Куча библиотек, которые используются от случая к случаю и многое другое. Да и от начального загрузчика, который работает до старта ОС никаких следов в в ОЗУ не остается, а ведь форматирование удалит и его. И без него ОС никто не запустит

Answer (score 2):

1. смотря что подразумевать под термином «форматирование жёсткого диска» (правильнее — «блочного устройства», далее — «б.у.):

   - **пересоздание файловой системы** (далее — ф.с.) на существующем разделе б.у. (а разбивка на т.н. разделы — это возможность создать несколько «логических» б.у. на одном «физическом» б.у.) приведёт к формированию новых пустых таблиц размещения файлов. физически большая часть информации о существовавших файлах, каталогах и прочих объектах ф.с. останется «на месте», но доступ к этой информации «штатными» средствами станет невозможен.
   - **пересоздание раздела** на б.у. с точно такими же параметрами (начало/конец/сигнатура) не окажет влияния на ф.с., расположенную на этом разделе.
   - **удаление раздела** приведёт к невозможности доступа к ф.с. «штатными» средствами (хотя вся инфорамация и останется «на месте»).
   - **удаление раздела и создание нового, начинающегося с того же места на б.у., но с меньшим размером** приведёт к повреждению ф.с., располагавшейся на удалённом разделе (возможны и исключения, зависящие уже от самой ф.с.).
   - **удаление раздела и создание нового, начинающегося с того же места на б.у., но с большим размером** обычно никак не влияет на ф.с.
   - **пересоздание оглавления** б.у. приведёт к удалению информации о разделах (эквивалентно пункту «удаление раздела» выше)
2. и смотря что подразумевать под термином «код моей о.с.».

   1. отображённые в оперативную память файлы останутся доступными, как, собственно, и всё содержимое оперативной памяти.
   2. смогут ли работающие процессы «добраться» до объектов ф.с. в случае её повреждения (см. выше) зависит от многих обстоятельств: и от характера повреждений, и от типа ф.с., и от реализации поддержки данной ф.с. в коде ядра «вашей ос».

Comment: «код моей о.с.» ещё может быть содержимым папки C:\Users\Vasya\Desktop\MyOS

Comment: @norbornen, метак *unix* как бы намекает, что речь идёт не о dos-подобных операционных системах.

Comment: конечно подразумевалось содержимое каталога `/usr/src/myos`... это просто опечатка =)... Кстати при «пересоздании ФС» программой `mkfs.ntfs` по умолчанию затрутся все данные.

Comment: кстати, первый (и пока единственный) плюс за этот ответ перевалил мою репутацию за 50 тысяч (это памятка для себя)